# Helm - how to call helper functions in a loop?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to define n StatefulSets where n is the number of nodes required, set in values.yaml as nodeCount. I get an error that looks to be scope related, but I can't seem to get the scope sorted out. Am I missing something here?

The relevant content in my StatefulSet .yaml file:

```
{{ range $k, $v := until ( .Values.nodeCount | int) }}
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: {{ $.Release.Name }}  
  labels:
    app: {{ $.Release.Name }}
    chart: {{ template "myapp-on-kube.chart" . }}  #here's my call to _helpers
    release: {{ $.Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ $.Release.Service }}
```

The relevant content in _helpers.tpl:

```
{{/*
Create chart name and version as used by the chart label.
*/}}
{{- define "myapp-on-kube.chart" -}}
{{- printf "%s-%s" .Chart.Name .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
{{- end -}}
```

The error I get:

```
Error: render error in "myapp-on-kube/templates/statefulset.yaml": template: myapp-on-kube/templates/_helpers.tpl:31:25: executing "myapp-on-kube.chart" at <.Chart.Name>: can't evaluate field Chart in type int
```

Comment: Not sure, but StatefulSets will have the same .. name ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several of the Go templating constructs change the meaning of `.` to be the thing that's being looped over, and you need to use `$` to refer to the initial value.  Most of your template correctly refers to *e.g.* `$.Release.Name`, but when you invoke the helper template, it's using the current context rather than the root value.  Change:

```
chart: {{ template "myapp-on-kube.chart" $ }}
```

(Note that the template as you have it will declare several StatefulSets all with the same name, which won't go well.  I might create just one StatefulSet with `replicas: {{ .Values.nodeCount }}`.)

Comment: Thanks, that's super helpful. I'll have to find a good explanation of go sprig framework scoping, this has bitten me before. Good catch on the template names. I've changed the name to `{{ $.Release.Name }}-{{ $v }}` to keep each StatefulSet uniquely named. I unfortunately need to use n StatefulSets so I can control pod affinity per node. For example, if I have 3 nodes with 2 replicas per node, I need to set anti-affinity to prevent the node and it's replicas from running on the same host. I could be totally wrong, but this seemed like the best way to control this.